# using jwplayer without internet access

Tags: flash, streaming, jwplayer, rtmp, live-streaming

I am using jwplayer 6 to receive and play **RTMP live stream** from rtmp media streamer in my domain. I want to provide media service without internet access in my domain; however jwplayer needs to communicate its home at `p.jwpcdn.com`. I tried to change links and use local addresses in `jwplayer.js` file; but that wasn't effective. Is there another way to use `jwplayer` without internet and if not can you please recommend me another appropriate player?

Comment: I'm afraid JW6 needs to have an internet connection in order to function properly. If you need to use the player without a connection, I would use JW5. However, don't you need a connection in order to use RTMP?

Comment: My RTMP streamer server is into my domain and I want to provide service just into an interanet. I tried to find out resources about jwplayer 5; but it is an old version and it is difficult to find instructions for its configuration. Would you help me by introducing such tutorial about jwplayer 5?

Comment: For JW5, our support guides are here - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw5/

Comment: Thank you! I will test that and if that met my needs, I will tag your answer.